# c++ regular matching ABC HHHH fetID_3141 ProID_1045

Tags: c++

```
ABC HHHH fetID_3141 ProID_1045
```

The above is a string, I need to extract `fetID_3141` and `ProID_1045`, mainly I need the numbers `3141` and `1045`, how can I use C++ to do regular matching?

Comment: Use std::regex, regex is kind of made to solve these kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::regex` for this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::regex r("[a-zA-Z]+_([0-9]+)");
    std::smatch m;
    std::string s = "ABC HHHH fetID_3141 ProID_1045";
    while (std::regex_search(s, m, r))
    {
        std::cout << m[1] << std::endl;
        s = m.suffix().str();
    }
}
```